# Extend doctrine 2 model with new values for fields

Tags: inheritance, doctrine-orm, symfony

I'm making a symfony3 project using doctrine 2 and I have this situation in my database

base_item

```
Id | val1 | val2 | val3
-----------------------
1  |  a   |  b   |  c
```

item

```
Id | base | val1 | val2 | val4
-------------------------------
3  |  1   |   z  | NULL | d
```

the `base` column is a foreign key to `base_item`.
I'd like to create a model where item's class extends base_item and if the same field is declared in both tables then it behaves this way:

If item's value is null then use base_item's one (in this example `item.val2` is "b"), otherwise use item's value (in this example `item.val1` is "z").

Is such a thing possible? I haven't found anything looking on the internet

I know i could build the model's getters to do something similar without using inheritance:

```
getCurrentVal1() {
    return $this->val1 === null ? $this->base->getVal1() : $this->val1;
}
```

but i was wondering if a more elegant solution existed

Comment: Have you thought about saving process? How could Doctrine know where to save new value of e.g `val1`? It would be ambiguous. The way you want it to be done may cause many issues that you don't see now.

Comment: Well if i'm working on instances of BaseItem it will be saved in base_item, if i'm working on istances of Item it will be saved in the item table. Doesn't look like such an issue to me

Comment: Well yes, it is an issue. If your `item` has `val1 = null` and `getVal1()` getter will return `base_item`'s value, then it will be saved in `item` during the next time you `persist`the `item` although you didn't change this field. Doctrine will just call this getter to check it's value and compare to the original value (which was `null`).

Comment: Not if Doctrine knows this is a special case and handles it accordingly, it is obvious that if such an inheritance exists it has to be handled (for example, it could have the actual value stored somewhere), what i am asking is is this handling is already implemented in Doctrine in some way. I don't see these as impossible to overcome issues, they can be easily handled

Comment: This is not a special case, this is your business logic. Eh.. just do it in your code. But not the way you've shown in your question, because you would have issue that I've described above. Getter with default value of `base_item's` value should have different name, not `getVar1`, because it contains logic that you don't want to be persisted.

Comment: I'm sorry but I think you didn't understand my querstion. getVar1 was just an example on how i would've done it (then i would've noticed it saved the base value into the item table and probably changed method name and leave the classical getter as getVal1) but it has nothing to do with my question. I was wondering if Doctrine had some way to handle such a situation internally (not using special getters)

Comment: It'd be a special case if Doctrine supported this kind of inheritance. It's like saying that if doctrine didn't support multiple table inheritance and then someone asked if you can extend your model classes and you told them "this is not a special case, this is your business logic". "I'm sorry, Doctrine doesn't support this kind of inheritance internally" is a viable answer to my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked this question into doctrine's repository and I got confirmation this feature is not supported.

https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/issues/6308